# how to convert List<SomeType> to List<AnotherType>?

Tags: c#

I have two data types:

```
class MyDataType {
    public int Id;
    private int Field;
    public String AnotherFieldOrProperty;
    // + there are some methods
}

class MyDataTypeDescriptor {
    public int Id;
    public String Description;
}
```

I need to convert `List<MyDataType>` to `List<MyDataTypeDescriptor>` such a way:
`MyDataTypeDescriptor.Id = MyDataType.Id`
`MyDataTypeDescriptor.Description = MyDataType.ToString()`;

I guess C# can do that very easy and fast in just one line of code, but I don't know how because I'm not familar with such advanced techniques. Would someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it (where `myDataTypes` is your `List<MyDataType>`):

```
List<MyDataTypeDescriptor> myDataTypeDescriptors = 
     myDataTypes.Select(x => new MyDataTypeDescriptor 
                                 { 
                                      Id = x.Id, 
                                      Description = x.ToString() 
                                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(from i in list1 
 select new MyDataTypeDescriptor { Id = i.Id, Description = i.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use automapper to do this automagically for you if you don't want to write the iterator yourself..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using LINQ [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method:

```
List<MyDataType> list;
// Process list...
List<MyDataTypeDescriptor> result = 
    list.Select(x => new MyDataTypeDescriptor() { Id = x.Id, Description = x.ToString() }).
         ToList<MyDataTypeDescriptor>();
```

Or if you have a constructor for `MyDataTypeDescriptor` that takes an `Id` and a `Description`:

```
List<MyDataType> list;
// Process list...
List<MyDataTypeDescriptor> result = 
    list.Select(x => new MyDataTypeDescriptor(x.Id, x.ToString())).
         ToList<MyDataTypeDescriptor>();
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple conversions, you can use the `Select` method like this:

```
List<int> lstA = new List<int>();
List<string> lstB = lstA.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

For more compex conversions, you the `ConvertAll` function, like this:

```
List<int> lstA = new List<int>();
List<string> lstB = lstA.ConvertAll<string>(new Converter<int, string>(StringToInt));

public static string StringToInt(int value)
{
    return value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `LINQ`:

```
var listofMyDataTypeDescriptor = (from m in listOfMyDataType
                                 select new MyDataTypeDescriptor()
                                 {
                                     Id = m.Id,
                                     Description = m.ToString()
                                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually convert them, you'll have to iterate through the collection and create a new Descriptor for each DataType

```
var result = (from MyDataType m in listOfMyDataType select new MyDataTypeDescriptor
{
   Id = m.Id,
   Description = m.toString(),
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one more way

define an explicit user type conversion
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

then do

```
var newlist = MyDataTypleList.Cast<MyDataTypeDescriptor>().ToList();
```